# Django : How to use models from another app

Tags: django

I have got two apps: `homepage` and `blog`. I have a model `Post` in the app `blog`. I can use this model for the app `blog` but not for the app `homepage`.

How can I use this model in app `homepage`: I want to display some of my recent blog posts as links in my homepage.

blog/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import permalink

class Post(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=140)
    body=models.TextField()
    date=models.DateTimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

blog/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from blog.models import Post     
from . import views
urlpatterns = [ 
    url(r'^$', ListView.as_view(
        queryset=Post.objects.all().order_by("-date")[:25],
        template_name="blog/blog.php")),
]
```

This is how I displayed my recent blog post in app `blog` Template

```
{% for post in object_list %}
     <div id="post_list">
     <h2 class="header1"><a href="/blog/{{post.id}}">  {{ post.title }}</a></h2>
     <h5 class="date_time">{{ post.date }}</h5>
     {{ post.PostImage|safe }}
    <br>        
    <div id="button"><a href="/blog/{{post.id}}"><text class="buttonDefault" > READ POST </text></a></div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I want to display it similarly in homepage template.

Comment: What do you mean you can't use it? What isn't working?

Answer (score 21):

You can use models from other apps by importing them the same way you imported `permalink` from the Django models:

```
from django.db.models import permalink
```

It's difficult to tell you the exact import without knowing your project structure. It could be something like this:

```
from project.apps.blog.models import Post
```

To make your life easier you could use a decent IDE that resolves imports for you (like PyCharm for example).